# pushing data to a page showing error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am pushing data to a page using codeigniter controller

```
public function trial(){
            /* after commiting now show them the next page which will directly allow them to invest */
                            $usertable =$this->user_profile->getUserTable();               
                            $userId = $usertable['ORIG_ID'];
                            $facebookId = $this->Facebook->getUser();
                            $sidebarData = array(
                                'userName' => $this->user_profile->getUserName(), 
                                'facebookId' => $facebookId, 
                                'caller' => 'investment_bucket'
                        );
                         $headerData = array(
                            $this->history->getPreviousPageInArray(),
                            'userName' => $this->user_profile->getUserName(),
                            'facebookId' => $facebookId 

                        );
                            $investAmount = 100;
                            $loanPeriod = 60;
           $investdata = array(
                                'investAmount' => $investAmount ,
                                'loanPeriod ' => $loanPeriod,
                                'pathName' => 'invest'
                            );

                            $this->load->view('header', $headerData);   
                            $this->load->view('borrower_sidebar_view', $sidebarData);
                            $this->load->view("invest_created_basket_view",$investdata);
                            $this->load->view('footer');  
        }
```

But on the loading page it shows,

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: loanPeriod Filename: views/invest_created_basket_view.php
>   Line Number: 9

And here is where I am loading the data.

```
<input type ="text" value="<?php echo $investAmount; ?>" 
<input type ="text" value="<?php echo $loanPeriod ; ?>"
```

I cant figure out what the problem is .

Comment: 'loanPeriod ' typo. Change to 'loanPeriod' (remove trailing whitespace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have a simple typo in there. it's a trailing space in the array key `'loanPeriod '`

```
$investdata = array(
    'investAmount' => $investAmount ,
    'loanPeriod' => $loanPeriod,
    'pathName' => 'invest'
);
```

Comment: no problem, wanted to ask for the code of your view, then I just noticed that typo xD

Comment: Hey I fixed the typo, but I still don't get the loanPeriod on the View

Comment: then please post your view script

Comment: ahh I fixed it, Thanks for your answer !! I will put the tick after it let me :D